# Limit Law explanation: $\lim_{x\to c} [f(x) + g(x)]$ exists and $\lim_{x\to c} [f(x) + g(x)] = \lim_{x\to c} f(x) + \lim_{x\to c} g(x)$

Tags: calculus

I'm reading the limit laws from, Real numbers and Real Analysis by Ethan D. Block. Following are the relevant definitions and the theorem for the limit laws:

**Definition 3.2.1.** Let $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an open interval, let $c \in I$, let $f: I \setminus {c} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function and let $L \in \mathbb{R}$. The number $L$ is the limit of $f$ as $x$ goes to $c$, written $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = L$ if for each $\epsilon > 0$ there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $x \in I \setminus {c}$ and $|x-c| < \delta$ imply $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$. If $\lim_{x\to c} f(x) = L$, we also say that $f$ converges to $L$ as $x$ goes to $c$. If $f$ converges to some real number as $x$ goes to $c$, we say that $\lim_{x\to c} f(x)$ exists.
$(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists \delta > 0) [(x \in I \setminus {c} \land |x-c|<\delta) \to |f(x)-L| < \epsilon].$

**Definition 3.2.9.** Let $A, B$ be sets, let $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g: B \to \mathbb{R}$ be functions and let $k \in \mathbb{R}$. The function $f-g: A \cap B \to \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $(f - g)(x) = f(x) - g(x)$ for all $x \in A \cap B$.

**Theorem 3.2.10.** Let $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an open interval, let $c \in I$, let $f,g: I \setminus {c} \to \mathbb{R}$ be functions and let $k \in \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to c}g(x)$ exist. Part 2. $\lim_{x\to c}f - g$ exists and $\lim_{x\to c}f - g = \lim_{x\to c} f(x) - \lim_{x\to c} g(x)$.

Let $L = \lim_{x\to c} f(x)$ and $M = \lim_{x\to c} g(x)$.

In their proof for part (1), I have a couple questions:

- Where does the $\frac{\varepsilon}{2}$ come from?
- Why take the min of $\delta_{1}$, $\delta_{2}$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a common pattern when working with limits: as $\epsilon$ is arbitrary in the limit definition, you may use a fraction of the final one in each of the parts. For the same reason, as you only need to make sure that a $\delta$ exists, using the minimum of the various $\delta_i$ used in the various parts is enough to ensure that $\left | x - c\right | \lt \delta \Rightarrow \left | x - c\right | \lt \delta_i$.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta. Thank you for your response. It makes sense; however, I'm still confused about the structure of the proof. Can you recommend some text that provides more detailed proofs of the limit laws?

Comment: @Serge Ballesta. Thank you once again for clearing up both my concerns. I believe this answers my original question.